# Is there any way to change directory using C language?

Tags: c, directory, executable

Is there any way by which I can ***change to any directory*** by executing a ***C program***?

Comment: Are you looking for `cd`? Or are you looking for a way to actually set an active directory in C?

Comment: It's called a hammer! :P

Comment: This questions is often given as an exercise to students leaning unix-like OSs. If that is the case, pay careful attention to what Peter says about *which processes* can and can not be affected.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Depending on your OS there are different calls for changing the current directory. These will normally only change the current dir of the process running the executable. After the process exits you will be in the directory you started in.

Comment: Thanks Peter, so it seems that the physical change of directory will not take place .

Comment: The current directory is part of the state of a process (like open files, memory maps, environment variable...).  Usually a process can't change the state of another process (usually, debugger and so on may have special privileges, but that is another story).

Comment: And this is why 'cd' is a shell builtin, not a separate executable.

Comment: There is a workaround, use [code] cd \`whateverProgramThatPrintsDirToStdout\` [/code]

Answer (score 21):

The `chdir()` function. For more info, use `man chdir`.

Answer (score 12):

`chdir()` changes only the current working directory of the process but not of the context in which you are working. Suppose you execute a program in the terminal and your current directory is `/home/Documents`, then on executing a program having the following lines

```
chdir("cd ../Downloads");
```

will not change the working directory of the terminal, but changes that of the process only.

Comment: I am least confused, does "_chdir_" accept a "_cd_" command as a parameter? I thought it accepts a string representing a directory...

Answer (score 11):

Well, the POSIX command for changing the current directory is:

```
chdir(const char*path);
```

See the [recent POSIX documentation for `chdir()` is here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/chdir.html).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the [chdir()](http://www.manpagez.com/man/2/chdir/) function.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    system("C:\\windows\\notepad.exe");
    chdir("C:\\windows\\desktop");
    return 0;
}
```

As per [this](http://forums.devshed.com/c-programming-42/changing-directory-running-another-program-35625.html)