# Change of directory in Fortran in a non compiler-specific way

Tags: gcc, directory, fortran, intel-fortran

I wish to change the working directory in a Fortran 90 code. Is it possible to do this in a non compiler-specific way? Here is my code:

```
program change_directory
    integer :: ierr

    call system("mkdir -p myfolder/")
    !call system("cd myfolder/")   !doesn't work
    ierr = chdir("myfolder")
    if (ierr.NE.0) then
        write(*,'(A)') "warning: change of directory unsuccessful"
    end if

    open(unit=33,file="myfile.txt",iostat=ierr)
    if (ierr.EQ.0) then
        write(unit=33,fmt='(A)') "Test message"
        close(unit=33)
    end if
end program change_directory
```

Clearly, using `cd myfolder/` in a system call doesn't work.  The [Intel reference](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/511525) says I need to add '`use ifport`'.  There's no such mention in the [GCC reference](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.0/gfortran/CHDIR.html), though. Leaving out '`use ifport`', I can compile the above code under `ifort` without any trouble. When I put it in, however, it won't compile with gcc (because gcc doesn't have the `ifport` module)--and not only that, it won't compile under Intel Fortran either--I'm getting the following error:

```
$ ifort change_dir.f90 -o change_dir
change_dir.f90(5): error #6552: The CALL statement is invoking a function subprogram as a subroutine.   [SYSTEM]
    call system("mkdir -p myfolder/")
---------^
compilation aborted for change_dir.f90 (code 1)
```

So my question is the following: is there a better way to do this? I'd like to keep my code as compiler-independent as possible. At the moment, I primary use gfortran/ifort and mpif90/mpiifort.

Answer (score 4):

See also [Is there any way to change directory using C language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293660/is-there-any-way-to-change-directory-using-c-language) . You can make your own interface to the `chdir()` [POSIX call](http://linux.die.net/man/3/chdir) to be independent of the Intel's interface. On Windows it is similar.

```
module chdir_mod

  implicit none

  interface
    integer function c_chdir(path) bind(C,name="chdir")
      use iso_c_binding
      character(kind=c_char) :: path(*)
    end function
  end interface

contains

  subroutine chdir(path, err)
    use iso_c_binding
    character(*) :: path
    integer, optional, intent(out) :: err
    integer :: loc_err

    loc_err =  c_chdir(path//c_null_char)

    if (present(err)) err = loc_err
  end subroutine
end module chdir_mod


program test

  use chdir_mod

  call chdir("/")

  call system("ls -l")

end
```

and when run

```
> gfortran chdir.f90 
> ./a.out 
celkem 120
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 15. říj 14.42 bin
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root  4096 15. říj 14.43 boot
...
```

On `ifort` it works too as it does on `sunf90`.

(Note: this relies on default `character` being the same as `c_char`. That is quite a safe assumption. If it is not the case the compiler will complain and a conversion has to be made.)